# converting string to int in client server socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, math

my project is basically a client sends a number to server. it calculate then return the value to client using TCP

there are three sections:

a) Sum of Product of given Numbers.
b) Perform String Operations. (Find, Reverse String, Split String) 
c) Display 10 Prime Numbers.

I am really stuck in it... I started with the server

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*; 
import java.math.*;
 public class G3server {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, IOException

     { 



            System.out.println("Waiting for Connection Request ................"); 
            ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(100); 
            Socket client= server.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Connected to Client ................"); 
            DataInputStream dis= new DataInputStream(System.in);
             DataInputStream din= new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
              DataOutputStream dout= new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 


      String choice,reply; 
do { 

choice=din.readUTF();
 switch(choice) {
  //sum of product 
   case "1":

       byte z[]=new byte[10];
      DatagramPacket dpack=new DatagramPacket(z, z.length);
       String s;

     String a,b,c,d;


      server.receive(dpack);
       s=new String(dpack.getData(), 0, dpack.getLength());
       int num1= Integer.parseInt(s);


         server.receive(dpack);   
       s=new String(dpack.getData(), 0, dpack.getLength());
       int num2= Integer.parseInt(s);

 server.receive(dpack);

       s=new String(dpack.getData(), 0, dpack.getLength());
       int num3= Integer.parseInt(s);

 server.receive(dpack);
       s=new String(dpack.getData(), 0, dpack.getLength());
       int dnum4= Integer.parseInt(s);

        reply=(a*b)+(c*d);

 z= (String.toInteger(reply)).getBytes();  

       dpack = new DatagramPacket(z, z.length, dpack.getAddress(), dpack.getPort()); 

 dout.writeUTF(reply);

              break;

// string operations


 case "2": /*

 bid=din.readUTF();

  sid=din.readUTF(); 

      dout.writeUTF(reply);
     break;
     */
     //Primes

     case "3":

       int i;
       String n;

     n=din.readUTF();

     for (i = 2; i <= n/2; i++) 


       { if (n/ i == 0) {


      reply="The number is not prime";



          break; } }

        reply="The number is prime";


          dout.writeUTF(reply);

  break; 
 case "4":

  System.out.println("Client Disconnected");
  break; } }
  while(!choice.equals("4"));

   } }
```

leave case 2 and 3 and 4 for now !!

in case 1

Q1)  why an error accrue saying that A B C D are strings while I initiated them as integers ?

Q2) is my converting correct .... I feel it isn't !

case 2

Q1) I really feel is it so complicated even though I read codes from the internet, any help in simplifying it ? 
maybe doing a separate case for each one ?

case 3

Q1) mismatching data type issues ... the solution is to convert

the client my friend is doing it ..... that is another story

Answer (score 0):

you declared
String a,b,c,d;
and doing  reply=(a*b)+(c*d);//you can't perform all arithmetic operation on string's

use,
reply=String.valueof((num1*num2)+(num3*num4));

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you modify your program a litte. since you want to send strings and integers, i would start by implementing a container-class.

sth like `Message<T>` that implements Serializable. In this way you can easily send data back and forth. Then, instead of using DataInput/OutputStream you should use an ObjectOutput/InputStream, makes it easier in my opinion.

too, as far as i can see you try to send datagram packets but you use a TCP connection, that wont work since datagrampackets are used for UDP connection (connection-less)

have at look at those specifications:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

i think the method readUTF() is also deprecated, as far as i can remember.

Q1: you do mathematical operations on a string, thats impossible.